# Trim Method Doesn't Clear All Spaces

Tags: c#, winforms, string, trim

Hi i'm working on a basic windows form in c# and I have a little problem with the *Trim()* method.
There are 3 text boxes in witch the user enters his first name, last name and an ID.
Then he can save the info by clicking on a save button but I want to make sure that he doesn't leave blank boxes so I do the following test:

```
        string CFN = Curator_FN.Text;
        string CLN = CURATOR_LN.Text;
        string CID = CURATOR_ID.Text;

        Curator_FN.Text.Trim();
        CURATOR_ID.Text.Trim();
        CURATOR_LN.Text.Trim();

        if (((Curator_FN.Text.Length == 0) || (CURATOR_ID.Text.Length == 0) || (CURATOR_LN.Text.Length == 0)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Have to enter a First Name, a Last Name and an ID");
            Empty = true;
        }
```

The problem is if I just make some blank space with the space bar the *Trim()* method doesn't consider them as a blank space..
Maybe I just misunderstand the *Trim()* method and if I do, do you have any idea on how I could do the this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Trim` method does not modify the contents of the text boxes, it simply *returns* the trimmed version. You need to store this version, for example

```
Curator_FN.Text = Curator_FN.Text.Trim();
```

Of course this has the potential to make changes visible to the user (and it also has to access the UI thread which under other circumstances might be a problem), so it is far better to use a local variable as in

```
var curatorFn = Curator_FN.Text.Trim(); 
// etc

if (curatorFn.Length == 0 || ... ) {
    // show messagebox
}
```

Of course if this is all you need to do, using [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) might be a more convenient alternative.

Comment: And if I just input some spaces will the *IsNullOrEmpty* method recognize the string as empty?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: Sorry, made a mistake by force of habit. `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is the correct method, and yes it will recognize spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Since strings are immutable in C#, the Trim() method doesn't change the string itself; it returns a new instance of the trimmed string.

You need to assign the results of the method calls to the variables, i.e.

```
CFN = Curator_FN.Text.Trim()
```

And then check whether or not CFN is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Trim does not modify the string.  You want:

```
Curator_FN.Text = Curator_FN.Text.Trim();
CURATOR_ID.Text = CURATOR_ID.Text.Trim();
CURATOR_LN.Text = CURATOR_LN.Text.Trim();
```

Also, if you're using .NET 4 you might want to check into the [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method as well.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Curator_FN.Text) ||
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CURATOR_ID.Text) ||
    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CURATOR_LN.Text)
{
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trim does not modify the string itself.  It returns a new trimmed string.

If you don't really care about modifying the variable, look at the [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method.

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(curatorFn) || ... ) {
    // show messagebox
}
```

Comment: And if I just input some spaces will the IsNullOrEmpty method recognize the string as empty?